# Unsure of how to store integers from a file to a struct in c

Tags: c, struct, segmentation-fault, void-pointers

I created two structs to store values in.

```
struct pair {
    int x_pos;
    int y_pos;
};

struct coordinates_header {
    int length;
    struct pair data[1000];
};

typedef struct coordinates_header coordinates;
coordinates *coords;
```

I then try to store data from a file using

```
char line[max_read];
int x, y;
FILE *in_file = fopen(filename, "r");
int i = 0;
coordinates *new = (coordinates *)coords;
while (fgets(line,max_read,in_file) != NULL) {
        sscanf(line,"%d %d", &x, &y);
        new -> data[i].x_pos = x;
        new -> data[i].y_pos = y;
        i++;
    }
new -> length = i;
```

Then I try to print out the values

```
int print_struct(void *coords) {
    coordinates *new = (coordinates *)coords;
    for (int i = 0; i < new -> length; i++) {
        printf("%d, %d\n", new->data[i].x_pos, new->data[i].y_pos);
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

And then I get a segmentation fault
I was wondering if someone could point out where the error is. I have no experience with void but require the flexibility for the structure in some functions I'm going to use.

The file read will have the form

```
100 30
50 200
.. ..
```

Comment: 1) `i += 2;` --> `i++;` 2) `i <= new -> length;` --> `i < new->length;`

Comment: Show definition of `coords` and `coordinates`

Comment: See [ask] and provide a [mcve]. And don't use things you don't understand. `void *` should only be used under specific circumstances and from the code, your's are not one of them. Don't dfy type-checking, your compiler is your friend, not your foe!

Comment: Sorry forgot to add this

Comment: typedef struct coordinates_header coordinates;

Comment: You still have not shown what `coords` is. Please take the time to read how to post a [mcve]. We need to be able to copy your code *exactly* as shown and run it to see the same problem as described.

Comment: Some of the code was provided by the instructor including void so that it is compatible with all students, hopefully this explains any weird code decisions. Also I just started to learn c a week ago, so if you have any advice on how to deal with void in the future, I'd be grateful. Thanks

Comment: `coordinates *coords;` declares an uninitialized pointer. You must first allocate data block with `malloc()` and then assign the pointer to it to the variable `coords`.

Comment: would sizeof(coordinates_header) be the correct byte size?

Comment: Is `filename` just a pair of `x y` coords on each line?

Comment: 1. You need to set `coords` to point to a valid buffer. 2. `i <= new->length` needs to be `i < new->length` 3. You need to learn to use a debugger.

Comment: There is no point in having a pointer to `coords` (which is the reason for the segfault). Just declare a static variable `coordinates coords;` (no asterisk!) and replace all `->` with `.`.

Comment: Just a nit (more style to avoid confusion). You will want to avoid using `new` as a variable name as it is an allocation function in C++. Yes, it is technically OK in C, but for someone scanning your code, you may create a bit of confusion. As it is a style/readability issue -- it is completely up to you.

Answer (score 1):

I believe their are some mistakes in your code:

- Instead of using `coordinates *coords;`, which is just a dangling pointer not pointing anywhere in memory, you should just declare a structure member `coordinates coords`.
- Their is no need for `void*` pointers in your code. You would be better off using `coordinates *coords` to access the address of the structure member `coordinates coords`, instead of `void *coords`.
- You are not checking the return value of `FILE *in_file`, which could return `NULL` if not opened properly.
- It is always good to check the result of `sscanf()`, just incase two `x` and `y` coordinates were not found on a line.

With these recommendations, you can write your code like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NUMCOORDS 1000
#define MAXREAD 100

typedef struct {
    int x_pos;
    int y_pos;
} coords_t;

typedef struct {
    coords_t coords[NUMCOORDS];
    int length;
} coordinates_t;

void print_struct(coordinates_t *coordinates);

int main(void) {
    coordinates_t coordinates;
    char line[MAXREAD];
    FILE *in_file;
    int i = 0;

    in_file = fopen("coords.txt", "r");
    if (in_file == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error reading file.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while (fgets(line, MAXREAD, in_file) != NULL) {
        if (sscanf(line, "%d %d", &coordinates.coords[i].x_pos,
                                  &coordinates.coords[i].y_pos) != 2) {

            fprintf(stderr, "two coordinates(x, y) not found.\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        i++;
    }
    coordinates.length = i;

    print_struct(&coordinates);

    fclose(in_file);

    return 0;
}

void print_struct(coordinates_t *coordinates) {
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < coordinates->length; i++) {
        printf("%d, %d\n", coordinates->coords[i].x_pos, coordinates->coords[i].y_pos);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Kayanda if this answer helps, give it a tick.